# PHP Help, inserting user input into html code

Tags: php, html, input

I'm coding a site so that I can watch YouTube without flash player.

index.html >
[code]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Youtube4Tor</title>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<img src="http://twimgs.com/informationweek/byte/news/2012-August/YouTube-Logo.png" />
<h3>Watch YouTube Without Flash in Tor</h3>
<br />
<form action="play.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
Youtube URL:
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="video" /><br />
</td>
<td>
<p style="color: #F00">Type in the code after the url,<br /> eg. If the video URl is<br /> "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqUdI4AIDF0",<br /> type in: dqUdI4AIDF0</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><center><input type="submit" /></center></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

[/code]

I'm stuck on the PHP, you see, what I want it to do is to get what the user entered, and insert it here:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/**HERE** frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Aurora

Comment: you will get user input in "S_POST" global variable.  Use: src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_POST['video']?>"

Comment: You can't do thst unless you post form to self. You're better off imcluding play.php in index.html and passing a local variable.

Comment: Need to see what's inside `play.php`

Comment: This is what's in the play.php --> <center>
<h2>Enjoy.</h2>
<iframe width="630" height="354.375" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_POST['video']?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<p style="color:red;">Video not showing up? Did you follow the instructions?</p>
</center>
This is how I've done it: http://tor.youtubell.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you're planning on showing the `iframe`, but this works when placed inside the same page as the form: (Using `action=""` as the form's action).

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php if(isset($_POST['video']) && !empty($_POST['video']) ){ echo $_POST['video']; } ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Using:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['video']) && !empty($_POST['video']) ){ echo $_POST['video']; } ?>
```

I would need to know how you're planning to show it, and what you have inside the `play.php` file.

Let me know if this works for you. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

---

### Using sessions

You can also use [**sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) which I tend to think would be a more flexible method.

Here is an example which has everything inside one page, but you could use the session variable pretty much anywhere outside that page, just as long as `session_start();` is included, along with the session variable.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['video'] = $_POST['video'];
// echo $_SESSION['video']; // for testing purposes only
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Youtube4Tor</title>
</head>

<body>

<center>
<img src="http://twimgs.com/informationweek/byte/news/2012-August/YouTube-Logo.png" />
<h3>Watch YouTube Without Flash in Tor</h3>
<br />
<form action="" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
Youtube URL:
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="video" /><br />
</td>
<td>
<p style="color: #F00">Type in the code after the url,<br /> eg. If the video URl is<br /> "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqUdI4AIDF0",<br /> type in: dqUdI4AIDF0</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><center><input type="submit" /></center></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php if(isset($_SESSION['video']) && !empty($_SESSION['video']) ){ echo $_SESSION['video']; } ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

### Page 2 test

The same video showed up on another page that I created (I didn't have to re-enter the YouTube ID), using the following:

```
<?php
session_start();
// echo $_SESSION['video']; // just to echo the video ID
?>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php if(isset($_SESSION['video']) && !empty($_SESSION['video']) ){ echo $_SESSION['video']; } ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

---

**Here is another method using sessions:** (A better method, I think)

```
<?php
session_start();

$video = $_POST['video'] = $_SESSION['video'];
echo $video; // echo video ID number
echo "<hr>";
echo $_SESSION['video']; // echo video ID number test
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Youtube4Tor</title>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<img src="http://twimgs.com/informationweek/byte/news/2012-August/YouTube-Logo.png" />

<h3>Watch YouTube Without Flash in Tor</h3>
<br />
<form action="" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
Youtube URL:
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="video" /><br />
</td>
<td>
<p style="color: #F00">Type in the code after the url,<br /> eg. If the video URl is<br /> "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqUdI4AIDF0",<br /> type in: dqUdI4AIDF0</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><center><input type="submit" /></center></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Then if you were to create another page called `see_video.php` for example, you would see the same video on that page without re-entering the YouTube ID number:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['video']) && !empty($_SESSION['video']))
    {
    echo $_SESSION['video']; // echo video ID number
    }
else { echo "Sorry, no video chosen."; }
?>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php if(isset($_SESSION['video']) && !empty($_SESSION['video']) ){ echo $_SESSION['video']; } ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This is how I have done it. http://tor.youtubell.com                  This is what's in the play.php ---> <center>
<h2>Enjoy.</h2>
<iframe width="630" height="354.375" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_POST['video']?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<p style="color:red;">Video not showing up? Did you follow the instructions?</p>
</center>

Comment: You're welcome. I will be happy to help when I get back, I have to leave now, but will contact you when I return. @Aurora

Comment: Hi. Works fine when I tried it on your site. @Aurora

Comment: If you feel my answer fixed your problem, click the White checkmark till it turns Green to accept my answer. @Aurora